# Methods of Verifying Kubernetes Configuration

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, minikube

I've been working on a [small side project](https://github.com/dgp1130/chatter) to try and learn Kubernetes. I have a relatively simple cluster with two services, an ingress, and working on adding a Redis database now. I'm hosting this cluster in [Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE)](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/), but using [Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/) to run the cluster locally and try everything out before I commit any changes and push them to the prod environment in GKE.

During this project, I have noticed that GKE seems to have some slight differences in how it wants the configuration vs what works in Minikube. I've seen this previously with ingresses and now with persistent volumes.

For example, to run Redis with a persistent volume in GKE, I can use:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: chatter-db-deployment
  labels:
    app: chatter
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: chatter-db-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: chatter-db-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: master
        image: redis
        args: [
          "--save", "3600", "1", "300", "100", "60", "10000",
          "--appendonly", "yes",
        ]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
        volumeMounts:
        - name: chatter-db-storage
          mountPath: /data/
      volumes:
      - name: chatter-db-storage
        gcePersistentDisk:
          pdName: chatter-db-disk
          fsType: ext4
```

The `gcePersistentDisk` section at the end refers to a disk I created using `gcloud compute disks create`. However, this simply won't work in Minikube as I can't create disks that way.

Instead, I need to use:

```
      volumes:
      - name: chatter-db-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: chatter-db-claim
```

I also need to include separate configuration for a `PeristentVolume` and a `PersistentVolumeClaim`.

I can easily get something working in either Minikube **OR** GKE, but I'm not sure what is the best means of getting a config which works for both. Ideally, I want to have a single `k8s.yaml` file which deploys this app, and `kubectl apply -f k8s.yaml` should work for both environments, allowing me to test locally with Minikube and then push to GKE when I'm satisfied.

I understand that there are differences between the two environments and that will probably leak into the config to some extent, but there must be an effective means of verifying a config before pushing it? What are the best practices for testing a config? My questions mainly come down to:

1. Is it feasible to have a single Kubernetes config which can work for both GKE and Minikube?
2. If not, is it feasible to have a **mostly** shared Kubernetes config, which overrides the GKE and Minikube specific pieces?
3. How do existing projects solve this particular problem?
4. Is the best method to simply make a separate `dev` cluster in GKE and test on that, rather than bothering with Minikube at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have found some parts of Kubernetes configuration that was not perfect from the beginning. But there are newer solutions.

### Storage abstraction

The idea in *newer* Kubernetes releases is that your **application configuration** is a *Deployment* with Volumes that refers to *PersistentVolumeClaim* for a *StorageClass*.

While [StorageClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#class) and *PersistentVolume* belongs more to the **infrastructure configuration**.

See [Configure a Pod to Use a PersistentVolume for Storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/) on how to configure a *Persistent Volume* for Minikube. For GKE you configure a *Persistent Volume* with *GCEPersistentDisk* or if you want to deploy your app to AWS you may use a *Persistent Volume* for *AWSElasticBlockStore*.

### Ingress and Service abstraction

`Service` with type *LoadBalancer* and *NodePort* in combination with `Ingress` does not work the same way across cloud providers and [Ingress Controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/). In addition, *Services Mesh* implementations like [Istio](https://istio.io/) have introduced `VirtualService`. The plan is to improve this situation with [Ingress v2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ne9UJL6irXY) as how I understand it.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details here fleshing out the problem a little more clearly, though I'm not sure I see a solution here. What is the difference between **application** configuration and **infrastructure** configuration? Are you suggesting that I could have one config with my general application configs and a separate one for Minikube/GKE specific pieces? Or is this simply a known design flaw in Kubernetes, which is intended to be "fixed" at some point?

Comment: @DouglasParker the application configuration is the same for all platforms e.g. Minikube and GKE. But the infrastructure configuration depends on the platform, e.g. is different for Minikube and GKE, hopefully this is a very small part of your configuration.

Comment: @DouglasParker yes, Service and Ingress may be a little different on each platform... it is easiest if you can use the same Ingress Controller on each platform... but sometimes you want to use the cloud providers setup.... so it depends on what is most important for you.

Comment: But my link about Persistent Volume explains how to do PersistenVolumes for Minikube... so it would be good to configure a common StorageClass across your platforms... but use a platform-dependent PersistentVolume.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand the concept but I'm struggling with the implementation. To focus on PVs specifically right now, would I use one `StorageClass` for Minikube and another for GKE, then just reference the `StorageClass` from my `PersistentVolume`? If so, how do I get the configuration to use the right `StorageClass`? The only method I see is to have an `app.yaml`, `minikube.yaml`, and `gke.yaml` with the same `StorageClass` name but different implementations. Then just `kubectl apply - f` the two that I want. Is there a better way of doing this or am I way off base here?

Comment: @DouglasParker yes. Your app uses a `PersistentVolumeClaim` that refers to a `StorageClassName`... that name is the same on both Minikube and GKE, but the StorageClass object binds to different underlying implementations... but the name is the same across platforms. See my linked example, they use `StorageClassName: manual`.

Comment: So, yes, you use one StorageClass for Minikube and another for GKE, but the have the same name... so the application bounds to the volumetype that is defined for the platform under the same storageClassName.

Comment: Here is an example for GKE for SSD: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/ssd-pd ...and if you define your on Minikube, you can also use the name `faster` to be compatible.

Comment: @DouglasParker yes, you did everything correct. But the `StorageClass` do you only have to create _once_ per platform. For every application project you create, you only have to use `app1.yaml`, `app2.yaml` and so on... You get three files now, because you are initializing two different platform at the same time you create your first app.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion here! I was able to split out into separate Minikube and GKE files which contain infrastructure-specific configurations while referencing them from a common `app.yaml`. I actually did it by splitting the `PersistentVolumeClaim`, as I couldn't find a good way of implementing Minikube using just a `StorageClass`.  This seems sufficient for what I'm trying to do. I'll have to refactor my ingress configuration to use the same trick. [My commit solving this problem](https://github.com/dgp1130/chatter/commit/e128e469f811f268b837dc5029cf2d560059c02f).